Clean Architecture - Chapter 23: Presenters and Views
Everyone!
While reading Chapter 23 of the book Clean Architecture, specifically the Presenters and Views section, I came across something rather unexpected where Uncle Bob states:

Every button on the screen will have a name. That name will be a string in the
View Model, placed there by the presenter. If those buttons should be grayed out,
the Presenter will set an appropriate boolean flag in the View model. Every
menu item name is a string in the View model, loaded by the Presenter. The
names for every radio button, check box, and text field are loaded, by the
Presenter, into appropriate strings and booleans in the View model. Tables of
numbers that should be displayed on the screen are loaded, by the Presenter, into
tables of properly formatted strings in the View model.

I found this approach curious and had to reread it several times to fully grasp the idea. While the passage is clear, it surprised me because I always associated Clean Architecture with how we handle Business Logic: focusing on business rules, keeping them decoupled and "clean."
This passage made me realize that not everything in Clean Architecture revolves around Business Logic, which raised some questions:

Uncle Bob mentions that the Presenter is responsible for loading
data such as button names and flags indicating whether they are
enabled. This intrigued me because I typically consider this the
View's responsibility. I never thought the Presenter would handle
aspects so closely tied to the interface, like button texts. This
makes me wonder: if button data comes from the Presenter, does the
same apply to other texts and even navigation?
If texts, navigation, and other interface-related data are managed
by the Presenter, how would this be implemented? I can't imagine use
cases or entities working together to construct a screen that has no
business rules, just display data.

In my experience, I separate the application into features that always include use cases and entities. I use the Presenter solely to translate the use case response into something the View can easily consume, typically in the form of a View Model. For me, aspects like navigation and text rendering have always been the View's responsibility, as they aren't directly tied to any business rules.
Perhaps my perspective is heavily influenced by my work as a front-end web developer.

You don't really explain your normal approach and how it differs. Surely if you have a button which can be disabled in some circumstance, then you have some IsButtonDisabled field on your view model and check that in your view?

Its worth noting that the world of MVC, MVM, MVVM, Whatever-Presenter-Whatever, Whatever-View-Whatever, Your-Grandmas-Way-of-Doing-It, there are so many opinions that are misleading (or sometimes just wrong) its not even funny.  I tell anyone who is trying to understand view/model/presenter patterns to read this article as some food-for-thought:
https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-more-mvc-frameworks/

This question demonstrates what comes out when people take Bob Martin's ideas too literally. Oh dear :-(
The chapter before the section you cited is titled "The Humble Object Pattern". The author summarizes its essential idea as

Split the behaviors into two modules or classes. One of those modules is humble; it contains all the hard-to-test behaviors stripped down to their barest essence. The other module contains all the testable behaviors that were stripped out of the humble object.

In the following short chapter "Presenters and Views", he gives a simplified example of what that could mean for presenters and views. Note that is a only a rough scetch, staying framework and vendor agnostic. It takes the whole idea to the extreme, probably for the sake of showing how almost everything in a presenter could possibly made testable, given the view is made as dumb as theoretically possible.
From that, don't make the mistake to conclude that for implementing an GUI application in a "clean architecture manner" (whatever that means), you should blindly follow these words literally and dogmatically. In the context of real UI frameworks, real UI components and real application infrastructre, there exist lot of efficient tools and solutions which make it unnecessary to strip every part of an UI down to strings and booleans just for the sake of automatic testability. Such an extreme breakdown might allow you to implement brittle tests for whether a menu item is named as it was named, but that's not necessarily a test which will be cost-effective.
In real-world applications, you make tradeoffs: you work with descriptive parts of a UI (where you rely on a tested framework which interprets the descriptions right), you use ready-made components and rely on the vendor having tested those components for you, and you may use designer tools which save you hours of hard work for the price of not letting you break the whole view down to strings and booleans.
I am sure Bob Martin knows that - however, the space he has reserved for that chapter in the book was simply too small to go into all these details in-depth, hence he could only present the core ideas straight to the point. Do yourself a favor and don't forget that when you read such a book.


"I use the Presenter solely to translate the use case response into something the View can easily consume, typically in the form of a View Model.  [...]
Perhaps my perspective is heavily influenced by my work as a front-end web developer."

Some Background for Context
I think it'll be helpful if I provide some context, and then circle back to your question.
The way you used "view model" suggests to me that you're thinking of it as of a simple, fully or largely behaviorless data structure that is to be consumed by the view, which is fine, but that's not what that term originally meant.
In fact, the word "model" itself does not imply behaviorless data structures, though it's often used that way in the industry (e.g. "models" for database entities or API responses, which is arguably a misguided use of the term). It simply means "a representation" - when it comes to code, it's the way something is conceptualized and embodied in code (and it might involve behavioral properties of that code).
In desktop applications, one approach to implement the presentation layer was to keep the views (the code intimately related to user controls and forms and their generic functionality) very "dumb", and to have a separate class (or perhaps, a small bundle of them), termed presentation model, that would govern the presentation logic: the application-specific aspects of how the view should behave (what to enable/disable and when, what to highlight, what to show in response to some action, things like that). Note that this is not business logic; nothing in the use cases or entities knows anything about buttons or check boxes or whatever. So, the presentation model is an abstract representation of the view (or a model of the view), that actually implements the presentation logic.
This would then typically use some form of data binding to largely automate the back and forth translation of data as needed by the controls, vs how it was represented in the presentation model itself.
When Microsoft came out with WPF (a desktop GUI framework), they used the term "view model" instead of "presentation model" for this, and the term spread, but what people meant by "view model" was not always the same.
Now, there are variations of this scheme where more behavior is put into the views, but generally, the role of the presenter is to govern the presentation logic (not simply to manage UI data), and so it's entirely a part of the presentation layer. So it's relatively closely tied to the UI.
The Presenter is just a part of the UI layer

"For me, aspects like navigation and text rendering have always been
the View's responsibility, as they aren't directly tied to any
business rules."

Well, sure, but that doesn't mean that it all has to be implemented in the same class. In other words, you can think of the presenter as just a class (or a small set of functions + data types, if your approach is more procedural or functional, rather than OO) that you've extracted from your UI code so that you can write the presentation logic more cleanly, without getting bogged down with the details of how things are actually rendered, or the peculiarities associated with particular UI controls. And, as Doc Brown's answer points out, it also allows you to write unit tests for the presenter. The main drawback there is that doing this often requires some boilerplate that syncs the presenters and the views (thus data binding).
That said, you might use some other scheme (or an external library), rather than the presenter, to do some of the things Robert Martin talks about - e.g. you might use some library to load language-specific interface text.

"If texts, navigation, and other interface-related data are managed by
the Presenter, how would this be implemented? I can't imagine use
cases or entities working together to construct a screen that has no
business rules, just display data."

It's really no different than just having the views, it's just that some of the responsibility that would have been in the views is now handled by an extra class (the presenter). It's just separation of concerns. The presenter is still a part of the presentation layer, and it depends on something in the use cases layer. E.g. it might use some data types or call some functions defined in the use cases layer (if the views/presenters tend to "pull" data from the inner layer). Alternatively, the presenter might implement an "output" interface defined in the use cases layer (if the use cases need to "push" data to interested consumers, without knowing what they are). Note that the "implements" relationship here crosses an architectural boundary (dependency inversion - the dependency direction is opposite to that of the data flow).
The use cases layer knows nothing about the views/presentation, and it provides functions and/or interfaces that are expressed entirely in terms appropriate for that layer, meaning, these do not assume anything about what kinds of views consume them - in principle, these should work equally well with a desktop GUI, a terminal, or a web interface, or IDK, some AI that can reliably translate verbal commands into function calls. This is achievable, but in practice, because the presenter has to take the response from the use case and translate it to the GUI format, and vice versa, there's a cost involved, so your design is somewhat constrained by it in terms of how different the two representations can be.
In the "pull" variant, your presentation-layer code simply calls a method on a use case. In the "push" variant, you'd dependency-inject a presenter (which remember, is an implementation of an abstraction required by the use case) into the use case. (This is true even in a dynamic language where you don't actually have to inherit from a class/interface - there, the abstraction is the spec of this "output port" associated with the use case, even if it only exists in the documentation). This is fine because all the use case sees is the abstraction, which is "owned" by the use case, and in principle has no view-specific aspects to it (though in practice, sometimes that might not be entirely true due to the aforementioned cost, or simply because a choice of some framework forces you to pollute your use cases layer). Sometimes, the role of a dependency-injected presenter can be fulfilled by a simple lambda (the abstraction in that case is the required function signature).
P.S. Also, a heads up: "entities" is another one of those overloaded terms that means all kinds of things in different contexts. In CA terminology, "entities" are also not simple behaviorless data structures, but proper objects that have functionality to them, that model the core business/domain concepts and capture the associated business logic.

So, does that mean the presenter is not necessarily tied to translating the responses of my use case but rather acts as a provider of information for my view? In this way, I could have a screen with no business rules that would have only a Presenter, like "Screen About Presenter," which would load the necessary information for the view. Of course, this seems like an extreme example.

I understand that we can keep creating more and more abstractions to make things increasingly decoupled and organized, and in the end, everything is fine as long as we’re following the dependency flow. But I’d like to know—how far-fetched is my question above?

@Tozine - "like "Screen About Presenter," which would load the necessary information for the view" - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that, could you elaborate a bit further? Do you mean something like a view with dynamically generated content (on-the-fly UI) based on the data it needs to show? This is possible to varying levels of complexity (where simple, and relatively common, would be something like dynamically generated list items, while complex, but rare, the entire screen). Or did you mean something else?

What I really meant is having the presenter take responsibility for loading the data for the view, from the simplest things like texts, messages, and states (such as enabled/disabled elements, etc.), where the view would be generated dynamically. This shifts the responsibility for deciding what to display to the presenter, turning the view into a Humble Object, as simple as possible.
I believe this is now more of a question about the Presenter pattern - would it be normal to load this kind of data within it?

I agree with @DocBrown, except I will be even more blunt about his conclusion: don't expect to read what Bob Martin actually says, and learn anything useful by it.
Book standards
The problem with these industry pundits and gurus is that they are not held to the normal standard of professional authorship, which is that the book alone successfully imparts useful knowledge to the reader.
These books are the ramblings of practitioners who may well be proficient in executing their own development, and who apparently have ample skills in self-promotion, but have very weak skills in academic authorship or written exposition.
Years ago, if you read a book by, say, Peter Norton, you came away able to do things you couldn't do before, or understanding things you didn't know before. You didn't just come away with a thousand extra questions about what the hell he was talking about exactly.
Similarly, books and authors were not approved by other practitioners on the mere grounds that, if they squint, and if they give a little bit of leeway on the terminology, and finally if they interpolate what they already know but isn't in the book, then maybe the author is not wrong.
That pitiful bar is not the right standard. The standard is whether the book explains something to practitioners which those practitioners don't already know; it reproduces an understanding in the reader, doesn't just prove to other peers of the author that the author probably has an understanding.
UI frameworks
There are such a variety of UI frameworks, of different vintages, used in different contexts, which incorporate different ideas, and dovetail differently with certain other development practices or architectural styles.
For example there's very little technologically in common between how the UI works on a rich-client platform like Windows, and how it works in a web browser.
Perhaps most crucially, some frameworks are designed primarily to facilitate a total division of labour between those who design the look and feel of screens, the "skin" of the application, and those who design the basic mechanics and conceptual structure of the application.
These different frameworks are not all bound by the same substantial principles with minimal extra to say about applying those principles to each particular framework.
Therefore I would be very loath to take lessons on principles from any book author who doesn't discuss (and make sense in the process) several specific UI frameworks where those principles are actually applied.

I think you are perfectly right with the second half of this answer, still I think the criticism in the first half goes over the top. It pretty much condemns every software engineering book of the last 20 years. Granted, "Clean Architecture" is a book which - given the real complexity of the topic, can only be superficial with most of its content  - but that's more an issue of the topic not the author's fault,

@DocBrown, "It pretty much condemns every software engineering book of the last 20 years." - was my intention that transparent?  Nothing has improved in 20 years in this realm, and it's time to condemn a little more and sympathise a little less, and demand higher standards from authors who have had at least 20 years to up their game.

Sorry to go a bit off-topic, but are there any software engineering architecture books that you would recommend (to a relative newbie)? I have enjoyed many of your posts on here and I have learned a lot from them, and you've obviously got a tonne of experience, but I like reading books, so, hence my question. (+1) BTW :)

@JoeKing, alas not. It's much more difficult to think of useful advice than to air my own complaints! I think one point I'd make is that the architecture of an application - the highest-scale patterns and arrangements - are quite variable and sensitive to context in lots of different ways. What is typically missing from published works is any information about the author's context, or (which would be even better...) an attempt to enumerate how architecture varies according to different contexts.

An Application Is Much More Than Business Logic
An application is nothing but some kinds of logics. Notice the plurals.
There is Business Logic ofcourse and Control Flow Logic and Presentation Logic. These three main types of logics exists thats why there is such a thing as MVC.
There is also Database Logic. This is how you put data in database and retrieve. This is governed by how you normalized your database. There can also be Network Access Logic if you are getting any data from network or putting something there. For example, use a web service. There can also be Filing Logic if you access File System.
There can also be Linking Logic. This is how you move from page to page for example, without clicking left bar links or footer links. It can be server side redirection. It can be links to detail pages and back etc.
Why Its Not Good To Put All Presentation Logic In Views
Its because your views would already have some other logics. For example, in my ASP.Net Web Forms there already is Observer-Listener design pattern logic. You would atleast have event-handlers there.
The event-handlers are the entry points. They have the Control Flow logic. Its boilerplate code. btnSave_Click call a method to validate user input then divide into two parts on basis of validation being successful. In the happy part, insert or update in database then get data from database and fill fields. Then take the form in view mode. Finally show success message. This is an example of boilerplate code.
The point is, it do not matter to this flow which fields the UI have. If a field is added nothing needs to be changed in this event-handler. Its same as when Business Logic change nothing needs to be changed in the event-handler. Its really boilerplate code.
As the logic of validation of user-input is taken out and put into a Business Logic class, the filling of UI controls and their enabling/disabling is also taken out and moved to a Presenter class.
Do You Feel Dirty About The Presenter Class?
The view i.e. the form do not fill its controls or enable/disable them, it just pass them on to the presenter that do the things; or it do but depending on very specific information passed to it in the presenter object.
However you put it, the presenter has to have intimate knowledge about fields (UI Controls) of the view. This is what may feel dirty to you. Another object knowing about and manipulating internals of this object. But thats the point.
The point is, for any schema change - change in number of fields in the database table - you do not even have to look at the view except adding or removing tags. The whole filling, format transforming and enabling/disabling logic is in presenter.
Its same as if only what actions you perform on fields in database table changes, not the fields themselves - suppose you now calculate for example rent in a different way - then only your Business Logic class change.
Do you feel bad because of javascript files  at Presentation Layer? You don't. Then why feel bad about the presenters.
If you are working in dot net you can use partial classes for presenters.
Whats The Whole Point
The whole point is to not only reduce places you need to make changes to when you do a maintenance task but also and more importantly reduce the number of places you need to look at or have itch to look at to be sure you dont break a thing there because of the modification.
For example, if validation rules changed for user input and just that, no fields are changed, then you have to look at the Business Logic class of the entity only. You do not have to look at anything in the presentation layer or database access layer.
Once you have designed your code such that the view have only boilerplate code then you never have to look there for any kind of change. This reduces amount of work you have to do in all tasks. Its a great benefit.

It's just describing normal MVP. Presumably most apps you've worked on don't account for different languages, dynamic menus etc etc so you can just hardcode the strings into the View?

Imagine the app is internationalised. ie the button text changes depending on the language selected.

vm.BugButtonText = translationProvider.GetString(language, enum.BigButton);



Bad example. One could design an internationalized application and still place the localization at the View layer, so the view models (or presenters) don't even know about it. Or even create different Views (one for each language) all using the same presenter.

I think that would break the pattern. Your views would have to call out

potentially you might use a view per language for special cases, but it would be an odd approach to use globally

even in non i8n apps you might still use dynamic text

Localization in UIs should be a mechanism orthogonal to an MVP layering. The presenter separates just "testable logic" from the view. The text translation can happen at the view layer as well as at the presenter layer, wherever it is needed. Ideally, as a UI dev, the only thing you have to keep in mind is that the texts you are using somwhere in both layers are implemented in parts which are all translatable on its own, and the translation mechnism should be an a separated, orthogonal concern.

not really, the presentation layer is a good place for it and it fits the pattern. Sure you could do it in the view, but you would be breaking the pattern for no good reason
